# Eclipse project backup

Tags: eclipse, plugins, scripting, backup, dropbox

I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers and want something like that:
Eclipse should add current project (or open projects) to archive and copy the archive to specified folder on its (Eclipse) exit.
Is it possible with Eclipse built-in functionality - scripting, or plugin?
I don't want to use bat-files, Script Host or other external tools.
The global idea is to realize on-exit backup of my project between home and workplace using Dropbox, e.g. automated sending project backup to dropbox folder.
But current task is to realize local backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not keep your Project folder in Dropbox itself?

Comment: Thanks for the good idea, it's a rather simple thing)) But it is required instant internet access, because of the instant data exchange between Dropbox client and server while editing project code, which is not always convenient to me. I want save only the last project state (snapshot) before closing Eclipse.

Comment: No, internet connection is not required. While you are editing, you cna be offline. THe next time you get connect to internet, it will get synced.